# Why does my Xbox 360 sound constipated playing some games and not others?

Tags: xbox-360

My Xbox 360 seems to make a LOT more noise while playing COD:MW2 than COD:BO.

Is there a reason for this or am I just imagining things?

Also, is there a way to reduce the noise vibration makes?  It is a Xbox 360 Slim (4GB) console, about 6 months old.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the noise I detect with mine is from the DVD drive; second is the fans. Other than hardware modding to install quieter components, your other option is to tweak the area around the xbox. For example, place a piece of foam underneath it to absorb vibrations. Be careful not to block the ventilation.

Comment: althought the OP only has the 4GB storage capacity, for those with harddrives (>20GB most practical) one can copy the game data for games to the harddrive, all but eliminating the sound of the DVD drive (the disk is still needed to validate ownership of the game)

Answer (score 1):

have you installed the games? for me, the disc drive is by far the noisiest part. installing just does a disc check then runs the game from the HDD, so the only noise you'll hear then is the fans. still pretty substantial, my xbox always sounds like it's about to take off.

obviously, make sure it's well ventilated and not shoved in a corner or locked in a cabinet to help keep it cooler.